# How to make a disabled Textfield Scrollable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

TextField is already disabled but I want it to be scrollable even if it's disabled. Please help.

```
TextField(
  enabled: false,
  onChanged: (text) {
    setState(() {});
  },
  controller: _notes,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 14.0,
    fontFamily: CONFIG.init.FONT_STYLE['REGULAR'],
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  minLines: 4,
  maxLines: 5,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    labelText:'Notes)',
    border: new CustomBorderTextFieldSkin().getSkin(),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can custom wrap your text field with `SingleChildScrollView` and `ConstrainedBox` like this :

```
ConstrainedBox(
 constraints: BoxConstraints(
   minHeight: 100,
   maxHeight: 100,
 ),

 child: SingleChildScrollView(
   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
   reverse: true,

   child: TextField(
     enabled: false,
     onChanged: (text) {
       setState(() {});
     },
     controller: _notes,
     style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.black,
       fontSize: 14.0,
       fontFamily: CONFIG.init.FONT_STYLE['REGULAR'],
     ),
     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
     minLines: 4,
     maxLines: 5,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       filled: true,
       labelText:'Notes)',
       border: new CustomBorderTextFieldSkin().getSkin(),
     ),
   ),
   // ends the actual text box
 ),
```

)

Comment: Hi, appreciate the answer. However, the textfield itself was scrolled not the text inside the textfield. It should be text inside should be scrolled even the textfield is disabled.